# Naming Text file after Variable

Tags: c#, streamwriter

Hi i'm looking to name a file after the TID variable which is the transaction number which is entered in by the user in `streamwriter`. the transaction ID is also the `transactionIDLabel.Text` below. I was wondering If i could make the transaction ID (`int TID` or `TranasactionIDLabel.Text`) the name of the text file? Thanks.

```
     int TID;

   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter outputFile;
        outputFile = File.CreateText ("TID.txt");

        outputFile.WriteLine(InvestorNameLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine(AmountLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine(DateLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine(DaysInvestedLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine(RateLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine(InterestAmountLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine(TransactionIDLabel.Text);

        outputFile.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
outputFile = File.CreateText (TID.ToString()+".txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 using(StreamWriter sw=new StreamWriter(string.Concat(TransactionIDLabel.Text,".txt")))
                {
                 // Your code
                }
```